# ERR_ABORTED 404 (Nof found) CSS Stylesheet Symfony

Tags: css, symfony, google-chrome, local, stylesheet

I'm trying to add a CSS Stylesheet in Symfony with a classic link but it doesnt work i have the error "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" in my browser.
The path in my code is correct (as you can see below) but it doesnt work when i load the page.
I'm using the Symfony web server it might come from that .

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Bienvenue !{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    <link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
```

My website skeleton is the default composer one.

If you can help me find the issue it would be great.

Comment: Drop the /public prefix.  Just use /css/style.css

Comment: @Cerad Thanks I tried and it fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the asset command in twig:

href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}"

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#asset

Comment: Thanks i saw that i should use asset but i tried to keep it simple i'm a beginner in Symfony but thanks for your help ! I will definitly think about using it ;)